# Node JS post API endpoint not recognized in front end

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, express, sdk

I'm trying to make a post request using appwrite SDK in Node JS express and Vue JS. The SDK requires me to create an api post request to create new storage bucket in appwrite. The [DOCs](https://appwrite.io/docs/server/storage?sdk=nodejs-default#storageCreateBucket) for this particular request isn't explaining really how to create the api in node JS express. I'm really new to Node JS and I already succeeded at creating get request but whenever I create the post request I get `404 not found` error.

Node JS express file (server.js):
In this file there is get users request API which works perfectly fine.
And there is create bucket post request which when being called in frontend it comes back with a 404

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express(),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser");
port = 3080;

// Init SDK
const sdk = require("node-appwrite");
let client = new sdk.Client();
let users = new sdk.Users(client);
let storage = new sdk.Storage(client);

client
  .setEndpoint("http://localhost/v1") // Your API Endpoint
  .setProject("tailwinder") // Your project ID
  .setKey(
    "Secrer Key!"
  ); // Your secret API key

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../appwrite-app/build")));


//This get request works fine
//get user by ID
app.get("/v1/users/:id", (req, res) => {
  let promise = users.get(req.params.id);

  promise.then(
    function (response) {
      res.json(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
});

//This one isn't recognised in frontend
app.post("/v1/storage/buckets", function (req, res) {
  let promise = storage.createBucket("bucket_id", "bucket_name", "file");

  promise.then(
    function (response) {
      res.json(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on the port::${port}`);
});
```

bucketsServices.js:
Here I'm using fetch post request to the api endpoint but it's not working.

```
export async function createBucket() {
  const response = await fetch("/v1/storage/buckets", {
    method: "POST",
  });
  return await response.json();
}
```

Addcomponent.vue:
Here I'm calling out the createBucket function from vue js file

```
    bucketTesting() {
      createBucket().then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    },
```

The error which I assume it means that it's not reading my node js express post API:

```
bucketsService.js?993b:2          POST http://localhost:8080/v1/storage/buckets 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

A screenshot of the same error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Something is missing here and I can't really figure it out.

Comment: you are trying to access port 8080 but your code snippets say you are running on port 3080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making request to `localhost:8080` meanwhile your server is running at `localhost:3080`

I believe your vue is running at port 8080 that's why `/v1/storage/buckets` gets prefixed by `localhost:8080`

Try to provide full URL while making request

```
export async function createBucket() {
  const response = await fetch("localhost:3080/v1/storage/buckets", {
    method: "POST",
  });
  return await response.json();
}
```

Better way might be to add proxy to automatically redirect request to correct URL, but this should work for now. [This article might help with how to setup proxy in vue](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/vue-js-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-a562bad965eb)

Comment: Absolutely correct! The problem was that in vue.config.js file I was setting the proxy to the right one only for /v1/users and not /v1/buckets. I have changed it to /v1/ and now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @MostafaSaid: Hi Mostafa, I had a similar problem. In my vue.config.js the proxy is on localhost:3080. In chrome web tools, the request is always displayed with localhost:8080. But the request works fine. How did you deploy your node server on production? Thank you xpediter